# Is there an easy way to switch render effects?

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings, app-widgets, screen-brightness

I find myself changing render effects a lot on my Nexus One. During the day brightness is ok, but to read on bed it's extremely bright even on the lowest setting.

I find that going to `options`, `cyanogen`, `interface` (why not under display?), `render effects`, and selecting either `night mode` or `blue` works wonders. Even if still too bright, it's worlds better than before.

But going to that menu all the time is a pain.  Is there a widget or a patch to add to the notifications power bar or something?

Comment: @ce4 just looked at the activities list. the best bet is a link to CM options that take me directly to the `interface` page. so, a little better, but not a huge improvement. Went from 7 "clicks" to 4~5 (depending if the new shortcut is on the last home or you have to press Home twice to find it)

Comment: how did i miss that?!?! probably because i have 200 garbage items on the widget list :) awesome man, thanks. and that was a huge Ooops on my part.

Comment: No problem, I overlook things too. Made this an answer... better suited. If you want, you can remove these obsolete comments, I already did so too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reinstalled CM7 on a spare HTC Desire to check the procedure:

1. Long press on spare space of homescreen
2. Select "Widgets"
3. Select "RenderFX widget"
4. Choose color (night, red, etc.)
5. Place Widget.

Results in a toggle switch widget:

[image]

Comment: here they are called "RenderFX Widget" on #3 and have the cm7 icon in the widget list. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are different apps to change rendering effects, I think, and there's also an app to dim your screen way more if you're rooted:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.pruss.superdim

Otherwise, CyanogenMod does not have widgets for this. I think certain custom launchers (such as LauncherPro or ADWLauncher) have the option to create shortcuts to certain activities, so you could possibly add a shortcut straight to the render effects menu.

Comment: nexus one can't dim more than CM7.1 already dims it. unfortunately. Render effects are my only hope. ...Think i will have to delve into the code (which i never looked before) and expose the render effects to some activity.